# Nuxt v3 cookies generated in SSR not passed to subsequent calls on first load of website

Tags: nuxtjs3

I have a problem in Nuxt v3 with the first SSR rendering of a page generated by reading an API. The SSR flow on first load AFIK is as follows:

1. Load of page on server starts;
2. The client middleware (on SSR context) calls authentication API endpoints which returns a cookie (it's working as in https://nuxt.com/docs/getting-started/data-fetching#example-pass-cookies-from-server-side-api-calls-on-ssr-response )
3. The template starts rendering and calls an api which needs the cookie set in point 2, but it is not passed, thus the server side middleware blocks the call

This are the relevant parts of the code

Client global middleware (which loads the cookie) `middleware/auth.global.ts`:

```
import type { H3Event } from "h3"
import { useCookies } from "@vueuse/integrations/useCookies"
import { appendHeader } from "h3"

interface jwt {
    token: string
}

// from https://nuxt.com/docs/getting-started/data-fetching#example-pass-cookies-from-server-side-api-calls-on-ssr-response
const fetchWithCookie = async (event: H3Event, url: string) => {
    const res = await $fetch.raw(url)
    const cookies = (res.headers.get('set-cookie') || '').split(',')
    for (const cookie of cookies) {
        appendHeader(event, 'set-cookie', cookie)
    }
    return res._data
}

const authorize = async () => {
    if (process.client) {
        const { data } = await useFetch("/api/auth/jwt");
        const val = (new Date(JSON.parse(window.atob((data.value as jwt).token.split('.')[1])).exp)).getTime()
        return val
    } else if (process.server) {
        const event = useRequestEvent()
        const data: jwt = await fetchWithCookie(event, "/api/auth/jwt") as jwt;
        return (new Date(JSON.parse(Buffer.from(data.token.split('.')[1], 'base64').toString()).exp)).getTime()
    } else {
        return (new Date()).getTime()
    }
}

export default defineNuxtRouteMiddleware(async (to, from) => {
    const cookies = useCookies()

    const auth = cookies.get("auth")

    let expires
    if (auth === undefined) {
        expires = await authorize()
    } else if (new Date(auth) <= new Date()) {
        expires = await authorize()
    }
    if (expires) {
        cookies.set('auth', expires * 1000, {
            path: '/',
            expires: new Date(expires * 1000)
        })
    }
})
```

Server side auth `server/api/auth/jwt.get.ts` (basically the file that is called by the middleware):

```
import uniqid from 'uniqid'
import jwt from 'jsonwebtoken'
import ms from 'ms'

export default defineEventHandler(async (event) => {
    const user = uniqid()
    const time = new Date()
    const expiresIn = process.env.JWT_DURATION || '1d'
    const token = jwt.sign({
        user,
        time
    }, process.env.JWT_SECRET || 'default', {
        expiresIn
    })
    
    setCookie(event, 'token', token, {
        path: '/',
        secure: true,
        httpOnly: true,
        sameSite: 'strict',
        maxAge: ms(expiresIn)/1000 // measured in seconds, so divide by 1000
    })

    event.context.token = token

    return { token }
})
```

The (server side) middleware guard `server/middleware/auth.ts`:

```
import jwt from 'jsonwebtoken'

export default defineEventHandler(async (event) => {
    if (event.path?.startsWith('/api/') && event.path !== '/api/auth/jwt') {
        const cookie = getCookie(event, 'token') || event.context.token
        try {
            jwt.verify(cookie, process.env.JWT_SECRET || 'default')
        } catch (error) {
            return { 'error': error }
        }
    }
})
```

The page is like

```js
<template>
    <h1>Title</h1>
    <div v-for="datum in data">
        <p>{{ datum.id + 1 }} <strong>{{ datum.username }}</strong> <em>{{ datum.number }}</em></p>
    </div>
</template>
<script setup>
const { data } = await useFetch('/api/data/sample')
</script>
```

The auth cookie works and is set on the final response, in fact the problem is just on the first load of the page, subsequent calls works as expected (also SSR calls).

I've also tried to set the value in the context, but also in that way it does not work.

## UPDATE:

I've found a workaround that I leave here in case someone else find it helpful.

Instead of relying directly on the `useFetch()` I've wrapped it and if I'm on the server instead of passing through the method I'm fetching the data directly.

It looks like this:

```
export const useFetchWorkaround = async (options?: UseFetchOptions<any>) => {
    if (process.client) {
        return useFetch('/api/poc', options)
    } else if (process.server) {
        const fetchedData = await apiCall()
        const data = JSON.stringify(fetchedData)
        return { data }
    }
}
```

Of course the server needs a bit of makeover as well:

```
import { apiCall } from "../utils/poc"
export default defineEventHandler(async (event) => {
    return apiCall()
})
```

And the file that does the actual call:

```
const apiCall = async () => {
    return $fetch('EXTERNAL_ENDPOINT')
}

export { apiCall }
```

This is far from optimal, but I didn't find any other way